# Remove *all* duplicate rows, unless there's a "similar" row

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4),
                c(4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5))
   V1 V2
1:  1  4
2:  1  4
3:  1  4
4:  2  5
5:  2  5
6:  2  6
7:  2  7
8:  3  4
9:  4  5
```

I want to study the different values of `V2` for a given `V1`. However, if all values of `V2` for a given `V1` are the same, that doesn't interest me, so I want to remove such rows.

Looking at the example above, the first three rows are perfectly identical (`V1=1`, `V2=4`), so I wish to remove them.

However, the next four rows include two identical rows and others with a different `V2`. In this case, I want to show the three possible values of `V2` given `V1 = 2`: `(2, 5)`, `(2, 6)` and `(2, 7)`.

The last two rows have unique `V1`: that falls under the category of "all rows are perfectly identical", and so should be removed as well.

The best I could think of is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854620/2175231):

```
dt[!duplicated(dt) & !duplicated(dt, fromLast = TRUE), ]
   V1 V2
1:  2  6
2:  2  7
3:  3  4
4:  4  5
```

Which obviously isn't satisfactory: it removes the `(2,5)` pair, since it is duplicated, and it keeps the `(3,4)` and `(4,5)` pairs since they're unique and therefore not flagged by either `duplicated()` pass.

The other option would be simply calling

```
unique(dt)
   V1 V2
1:  1  4
2:  2  5
3:  2  6
4:  2  7
5:  3  4
6:  4  5
```

But it keeps the `(1,4)`, `(3,4)`, `(4,5)` pairs I want removed.

In the end, the result I'm looking for is:

```
   V1 V2
1:  2  5
2:  2  6
3:  2  7
```

Though any other format is also acceptable, such as:

```
   V1 V2.1 V2.2 V2.3
1:  2    5    6    7
```

(which shows the possible values of `V2` for each "interesting" `V1`)

I can't figure out how to differentiate the `(1,4)` case (all rows are the same) from the `(2,5)` case (there are some duplicates, but there are other rows with the same `V1`, so we must remove the duplicate `(2,5)` but leave one copy).

As for the unique rows, I've written a very ugly call, but it only works if there's only one unique row. If there's two, such as the example above, it fails.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: @akrun The expected ouput is given in the last two code blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to group by 'V1', get the index of group that has length of unique elements greater than 1 and then take the `unique`

```
unique(dt[dt[, .(i1 = .I[uniqueN(V2) > 1]), V1]$i1])
#   V1 V2
#1:  2  5
#2:  2  6
#3:  2  7
```

Or as @r2evans mentioned

```
unique(dt[, .SD[(uniqueN(V2) > 1)], by = "V1"])
```

NOTE: The OP's dataset is `data.table` and `data.table` methods are the natural way of doing it

---

If we need a `tidyverse` option, a comparable one to the above `data.table` option is

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
   group_by(V1) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(V2) > 1) %>% 
   distinct()
```

Comment: I was just about to post `unique(dt[,.SD[ (length(unique(V2)) > 1), ], by = "V1" ])` ... and now just learned about `uniqueN`, thanks :-)

Comment: Perhaps clearer? `unique(dt[, .SD[ (uniqueN(V2) > 1), ], by = "V1"])`

Comment: @r2evans  That is clean, but I think the `.I` would be faster from my previous benchmark experiments

Comment: Good to know, thanks. My experience with `data.table` doesn't yet hold an intuitive sense of comparative performance. ~10% improvement (median) is pretty good, wonder how it scales to "real" (not-small) datasets.

Comment: @r2evans There's a benchmark on a relatively large table in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093919/dplyrslice-in-data-table). Another option (not that more are needed) is `unique(dt[, if(uniqueN(V2) > 1) .SD, by = "V1"])`

Comment: This works like a charm, of course. I'm having trouble understanding how it works, though... How does `.I[uniqueN(V2) > 1]` work? `uniqueN(V2) > 1` returns `TRUE` (since there's more than one unique value), but when wrapped by `.I[]` (aka `seq_along`), it becomes `1, 2, ... nrows`. Is this a different `>` operator I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Wasabi What it does is `uniqueN(V2) > 1` gets a logical vector of length 1 for each group of 'V1' By wrapping with `.I`, it gives the row index of all the rows for that V1.  extract that row index column `$i1` and use that in `i` for ssubsetting the rows  and the wrap with `unique`

Answer (score 2):

Also one `dplyr` possibility:

```
dt %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(V2) != 1 & !duplicated(V2))

     V1    V2
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     5
2     2     6
3     2     7
```

Or:

```
dt %>%
 group_by(V1) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(V2) != 1) %>%
 group_by(V1, V2) %>%
 slice(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case with base `R`

```
dt[ave(dt$V2,dt$V1,FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))>1&!duplicated(dt)]
   V1 V2
1:  2  5
2:  2  6
3:  2  7
```

Comment: A small change to make it clearer could be `dt[with(dt,ave(V2,V1,FUN=function(x) length(unique(x)))>1&!duplicated(dt))]`.

Comment: What I want to know: with all of that base-R code-golf going on, you keep one space in the middle? ;-)

Comment: They have to save the extra whitespace for all of that mandatory indentation? (Full disclosure: I use python too, just not as proficient/vocal.)

Comment: @WeNYoBen, I'd be really impressed with a pandas version of this :-P

Comment: @r2evans keep the space is a good coding behavior which I should enhance:-) , `df[df.groupby('V1').V2.transform('nunique').gt(1)].drop_duplicates()
`

Answer (score 2):

Using an if statement allows for more concision and is, arguably, more `data.table`'ly:

```
dt[, if (uniqueN(V2) > 1) unique(V2), by = V1]

#    V1 V1
# 1:  2  5
# 2:  2  6
# 3:  2  7
```

But couldn't get the column names right...

A bit less concise solutions:

```
dt[, .(V2 = if (uniqueN(V2) > 1) unique(V2) else numeric(0)), by = V1]

dt[, .SD[if (uniqueN(V2) > 1) !duplicated(V2)], by = V1]

#    V1 V2
# 1:  2  5
# 2:  2  6
# 3:  2  7
```